# Alternatives to posting with your arms while grappling

Tags: training, safety, falling

This is question that I have been meaning to ask for a while.

Last November, I competed at a tournament, along with some of the others from my gym. After I left, I was informed that one of the fellow students had broken his arm during a match. I watched the video, and what happened was that both his legs were trapped and he tripped. He posted out with his arm to stop the fall, and his arm broke. This is the human body's natural reflex to falling, so was this the safest course of action he could have taken? And if I were to find myself in that situation, what could I do instead of posting that would prevent me from being injured?

Comment: In which direction did your teammate fall?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann if I remember correctly, he fell a little forward and to the side

Comment: I've done this before at home of all places. Stupidly locked my arm out. It didn't break my arm, but it did mess up my shoulder joint pretty bad. It healed on its own, but it's still kind of cranky every now and then. I didn't have the option of rolling out of it or turn to my side for a side breakfall, as there was a ton of hard, pointy objects on the floor at the time. Oh well.

Comment: The answers to this other question on breakfalls are also relevant: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/2354/5961

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When both legs are trapped, there are two relatively safe breakfall options left: onto the side of your body, if you can twist your upper body 90 degrees, or forwards.

Forward breakfall (Mae ukemi):

https://youtu.be/OegVa1MjMO8

Sidewards breakfall (Yoko ukemi:

https://youtu.be/gEdtaj5Mbmk

If possible, I'd always prefer the sidewards option over the forwards one with regards to safety, but properly trained, you can do the latter as well without much of a risk for injuries.

Another point to consider is vulnerability after you took the fall: falling frontwards leaves your back open, so you would like to fall sidewards and shrimp whenever possible.

Answer (score 6):

The two alternatives to posting with your arms are to execute the appropriate break-fall (as in orthodox judo/jujutsu *ukemi*) or to execute the appropriate turnout (as in modern [unorthodox competitive ukemi](http://betterjudo.com/articles/turnouts-unorthodox-ukemi/)).

For instance, one of the most common arm-snapping posts comes from being thrown forward and over the thrower's shoulders, such as in a *seoinage* (shoulder or back throw). In this scenario either option (traditional ukemi or modern turn-out) is possible, depending on the precise circumstances. A traditional break-fall would look like a forward roll followed by a side breakfall (*zenpo kaiten* to *yoko ukemi*), which is a core tumbling skill for any judoka or jiujitsiero. A modern turn-out might be a one-handed handstand or an over-rotation, landing on one's feet or on all fours. Another unorthodox approach is to hip-block and sidestep the shoulder throw, thus under-rotating and landing on one's chest and shoulder.

Comment: I really like this answer.  I believe the SE expression is a peal?

Comment: Thanks! What's "SE"? I've never heard of a "peal" in martial arts.

Comment: Sorry pearl. A good answer SE is Stack exchange.

Comment: Ahhhhhh right! Thank you :)

Comment: This is a great answer. One thing I will make clear if I didn't before is that both his legs were trapped when he fell, so landing on all fours or rolling out is particularly hard.

Comment: @LemmyX Judo coaches are consistent that posting with an arm is a Bad Idea unless you rrrreally know what you're doing (i.e. you're good at turnouts and your legs aren't trapped). In this scenario I'd say your teammate should've landed on their flank or back, or tried to post without resisting in order to execute a [front fall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUaIRS-Na_I).

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks